# Align block with margin

Tags: beamer, margins, block

I am using beamer with the inner theme `rectangles`. The text inside blocks is then aligned with the text outside of the blocks, and the edge of the blocks stick out into the margins. I would like the block edges to follow the margins. I searched for a solution, and the best I found was placing the block environment inside a `minipage` of the desired width and place this inside `center`.

I tried this, and it is roughly aligned on the left. However, now there is more white space on the right side of the block than on the left.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\setbeamersize{text margin left  = 1em, 
               text margin right = 1em}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
    \vspace{9.5mm}
    \vbox
    {
        \bfseries\LARGE\strut\structure{\insertframetitle}\strut
    }
    \vspace{-0.8em}
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{block}
{
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{0.9485\textwidth}
}

\AfterEndEnvironment{block}
{
         \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg = white, bg = structure}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{I}

        \begin{block}{I}

        \end{block}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I did understand you right. Here is a simplified version of the block definitions we use in the [mtheme](https://github.com/matze/mtheme), which is as far as I can tell exactly what you want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamersize{text margin left  = 1em, 
               text margin right = 1em}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \vspace{9.5mm}
  \vbox{%
    \bfseries\LARGE\strut\structure{\insertframetitle}\strut
  }
  \vspace{-0.8em}
}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg = white, bg = structure}

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \vspace*{1ex}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
    ht=2.4ex,
    dp=1ex,
    leftskip=0.5em,
    rightskip=0.5em]{block title}
      \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \vspace*{0.5em}
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
    dp=1ex,
    leftskip=0.5em,
    rightskip=0.5em,
    vmode]{block body}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}{%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vspace*{0.2ex}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Frametitle}
    \begin{block}{Blocktitle}
    Content of the block.
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The rectangle inner theme by the way does not do any changes with respect to the block definitions. So I removed it from your MWE.

[image: Screenshot]