# How to include an align environment in a block in LaTeX Beamer

Tags: beamer, align

I am trying to fit a formula in an `align` environment into a Block, using the document class `beamer`:

```
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Title1}
\begin{block}{Title2}
\begin{align}
y(t) &= g_1 x(t) + g_2 x^2(t) + g_3 x^3(t) \notag \\
x(t) &= A \cos(\omega_c t) \notag \\
\Rightarrow y(t) &= g_1 A \cos(\omega_c t) + g_2 A^2 \cos^2(\omega_c t) + g_3 A^3 \cos^3(\omega_c t) \notag \\
\Leftrightarrow y(t)& = g_1 A \cos(\omega_c t) + \frac{g_2 A^2}{2} (1 + \cos(2 \omega_c t)) + \frac{g_3 A^3}{4} (3 \cos(\omega_c t) + \cos(3 \omega_c t)) \notag \\
\Leftrightarrow y(t)& = \frac{g_2 A^2}{2} + \Big(g_1 A + \frac{3 g_3 A^3}{4}\Big) \cos(\omega_c t) + \frac{g_2 A^2}{2} \cos(\2 \omega_c t) + \frac{3 g_2 A^3}{4} \cos(\omega_c t) \notag
\end{align} 
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

Two problems occur:

- the third formula and also the fourth are too long to fit into the block/box.
- the fourth formula leads to an error: `undefined control sequence \end{frame}`

Comment: Hi, you could see at the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254135/align-block-with-margin

Comment: I get the following error message: `Undefined control sequence ... \2`. Is this a typo, or did you define `\2` somehow?

Comment: @Mico: that's a typo. But where did you find \2 ?

Comment: @ Mico: I found the typo, thanks! I don't get an error anymore. But the 3rd and 4th formula still don't fit in the box. How can I include a line break maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am unable to generate the error message you report. To make the final two equations fit in the textblock, just introduce two additional line breaks.

To provide for a more "even" look, consider using `\tfrac` (text style `\frac`) for `\tfrac{1}{4}`, `\tfrac{1}{2}`, and `\tfrac{3}{4}`. That way, the fraction expressions will be less visually dominant. And, by giving less visual prominence to the fractional terms, one automatically gives more visual prominence to the other factors; I take it that this is desirable for the equations at hand.

Also, since you're not using equation numbers anywhere, use an `align*` environment rather than an `align` environment. Doing so will let you get rid of five [5!] `\notag` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Title1}
\begin{block}{Title2}

\begin{align*}
y(t)                 &= g_1 x(t) + g_2 x^2(t) + g_3 x^3(t)  \\
x(t)                 &= A \cos(\omega_c t)  \\
\Rightarrow y(t)     &= g_1 A \cos(\omega_c t) + g_2 A^2 \cos^2(\omega_c t) 
                        + g_3 A^3 \cos^3(\omega_c t)  \\[1ex]
\Leftrightarrow y(t) &= g_1 A \cos(\omega_c t) + \tfrac{1}{2} g_2 A^2 
                        (1 + \cos(2 \omega_c t)) \\ %<-- new line break
                     &\quad + \tfrac{1}{4}g_3 A^3 \bigl(3 \cos(\omega_c t) 
                        + \cos(3 \omega_c t)\bigr)  \\[1ex]
\Leftrightarrow y(t) &= \tfrac{1}{2} g_2 A^2 + \bigl(g_1 A + 
                        \tfrac{3}{4} g_3 A^3\bigr) \cos(\omega_c t) \\ % <-- new line break
                     &\quad + \tfrac{1}{2}g_2 A^2 \cos(2 \omega_c t) 
                        + \tfrac{3}{4} g_2 A^3 \cos(\omega_c t)
\end{align*}

\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If your `beamer` document features a lot math material, it may be worth using a different font than Computer Modern Sans Serif (the default). For instance, adding the instructions

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{arev} % loads the 'arev' font family
```

to the code shown above generates the following output. The differences are especially noticeable in the `x` and `g` glyphs as well as in the fraction terms.

[image]

Comment: +1. Very good. Excuse me Mico. Can you edit your text? There are errors concerning backtipes escapes.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Thanks. I've added the missing backtick.

Comment: Probably best not to recommend `arev` at the moment. Some maths symbols will be silently omitted from the output. (It appears not to have been updated in light of changes to `mathdesign`.)